# Машиноместо или машино-место?

Tags: орфография

Грамота.ру дает вариант "машино-место". В Интернете можно увидеть оба варианта, слитное написание встречается даже чаще. Что выбираем и как объясняем? Может быть, в разных обстоятельствах разное написание?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. А если их различать по значению? Если это единица измерения, то пишем через дефис: стоянка на 300 машино-мест. Если это гаражный бокс, то пишем слитно: куплю машиноместо, размеры машиноместа - 2,5 м на 5 м.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 2. Смотря какая машина, а то может занять два машино-места. И вот ещё пара: самолетовылет и самолето-вылет. Какие варианты здесь возможны?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 3. Может быть, здесь также возможны два варианта? Например: Полк совершил за неделю 200 самолето-вылетов (это единица измерения объема работы). На каждый самолетовылет летчик получает задание (вылет самолета, термин, встречается редко). И насчет машино-места у меня есть сомнения. Может быть, можно это считать единицей измерения объема стоянки, даже если это просто площадь под машину?

Comment: Ваш "самолёто-вылет" вызвал недоумение.Ворд подчёркивает. Набрала "словарь Лопатина". Выщло http://lopatin.academic.ru/128444/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82-Орфографический словарь Лопатина -самолёто-в'ылет,(2009г.)

Русский орфографический словарь. / Российская академия наук. Ин-т рус. яз. им. В. В. Виноградова. — М.: "Азбуковник". В. В. Лопатин (ответственный редактор), Б. З. Букчина, Н. А. Еськова и др.. 1999.
http://vnz.ru/spravki/slovS.html -самолётовы́лет.   Не пойму, где действующий словарь.

Comment: http://lopatin.academic.ru/128444/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да,в настоящее время в правовых актах и федерального, и регионального уровня указанный термин  пишется по-разному: «машиноместо» или «машино-место».

Разноброд в написании объясняется тем, что это новое слово, оно появилось где-то в конце 90-х - начале 2000 - х, как и тоннаж-сутки и тоннажесутки, тонно-километраж и тоннокилометраж. Справочник Валгиной Н.С., Светлышевой В.Н. (Орфография и пунктуация: справочник.- М.: "Неолит", 2001)объясняет:
  Такие орфографические варианты можно объяснить наличием соединительных гласных (машин-о-место, тоннаж-е-сутки, тонн-о-километраж), т. е. сказывается влияние общего правила написания сложных слов с соединительной гласной, поэтому предпочтительнее писать эти слова и им подобные слитно.    http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.46

Однако Лопатин считает по-другому:
Следующие группы существительных, образуемых с соединительными гласными (как отступление от правила § 119, п. 3)пишем через дефис:
а) названия сложных единиц измерения, напр.: койко-место, машино-место, пассажиро-километр, тонно-километр, самолёто-вылет, станко-час,килограмм-час, человеко-день.Логика есть: как в других похожих словах(грамм-атом), чтобы не путаться, мы же давно пишем термины через дефис - и военные, и физические, и др.
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=66#pp66С

Как будто бы оба правы, но нам-то надо придерживаться мнения кого-то одного. Наверно, всё-таки Лопатина, если его словарь признан приоритетным для науки. Задания ЕГЭ, например, будут проверять по его словарю, а не по Валгиной

Answer (score 3):

Машиноместо, койкоместо — категорически за слитное написание. И это не сложная единица измерения в отличие от тонно-километров или человеко-дней, а банальная единица площади для одной машины.

Answer (score 1):

Слова, образованные на основе словосочетаний, пишутся слитно. Разве здесь не такой случай:место машины, место койки?